# Can we replace map with flatMap?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to find line with maximum words, and i wrote the following lines, to run on spark-shell:

```
import java.lang.Math

val counts = textFile.map(line => line.split(" ").size).reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))
```

But since, map is one to one , and `flatMap` is one to either zero or anything. So i tried replacing `map` with `flatMap`, in above code. But its giving error as:

```
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int
required: TraversableOnce[?]
   val counts = F1.flatMap(s => s.split(" ").size).reduce((a,b)=> Math.max(a,b))
```

If anybody could make me understand the reason, it will really be helpful.

Comment: what's your input like ?

Comment: textFile is having  lines:     "Hi everyone.I am good.infact so good.
Whether is so good. Lets go for outing.
I love travelling. its good for mind and soul."

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` must return an `Iterable` which is clearly not what you want. You do want a `map` because you want to map a line to the number of words, so you want a one-to-one function that takes a line and maps it to the number of words (though you could create a collection with one element, being the size of course...).

`FlatMap` is meant to associate a collection to an input, for instance if you wanted to map a line to all its words you would do:

```
val words = textFile.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
```

and that would return an `RDD[String]` containing all the words.

In the end, `map` transforms an `RDD` of size N into another `RDD` of size N (e.g. your lines to their length) whereas `flatMap` transforms an `RDD` of size N into an `RDD` of size P (actually an `RDD` of size N into an `RDD` of size N made of collections, all these collections are then flattened to produce the `RDD` of size P).

**P.S.:** one last word that has nothing to do with your problem, it is more efficient to do (for a string `s`)

```
val nbWords = s.split(" ").length
```

than call `.size()`. Indeed, the `split` method returns an array of `String` and arrays do not have a `size` method. So when you call `.size()` you have an implicit conversion from `Array[String]` to `SeqLike[String]` which creates new objects. But `Array[T]` do have a `length` field so there's no conversion calling `length`. (It's a detail but I think it's good habit though).

Comment: Not particularly relevant, but `length` on arrays is a field, not a method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7.

Comment: My P.S. wasn't really relevant anyway =) indeed it's a field, i'll edit my post, thxs!

Answer (score 0):

Any use of `map` can be replaced by `flatMap`, but the function argument has to be changed to return a single-element `List`: `textFile.flatMap(line => List(line.split(" ").size))`. This isn't a good idea: it just makes your code less understandable and less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions? Consider Using Java SE 8's Optional!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)'s part about why use flatMap() rather than Map(), I have realized the truly reason why flatMap() can not replace map() is that **map() is not a special case of flatMap()**.

**It's true that flatMap() means one-to-many, but that's not the only thing flatMap() does. It can also strip outer Stream() if put it simply.**

See the definations of map and flatMap:

```
Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper)
Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)
```

the only difference is the type of returned value in inner function. What map() returned is "Stream<'what inner function returned'>", while what flatMap() returned is just "what inner function returned".

So you can say that flatMap() can kick outer Stream() away, but map() can't. This is the most difference in my opinion, and also why map() is not just a special case of flatMap().

ps:

If you really want to make one-to-one with `flatMap`, then you should change it into one-to-List(one). That means you should add an outer Stream() manually which will be stripped by flatMap() later. After that you'll get the same effect as using map().(Certainly, it's clumsy. So don't do like that.)

Here are examples for Java8, but the same as Scala:

1. use `map()`:

   ```
    list.stream().map(line -> line.split(" ").length)
   ```
2. ***deprecated*** use `flatMap()`:

   ```
   list.stream().flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ").length).stream())
   ```